# Calling request in the callback of a previous call

Tags: javascript

My issue is that I want to loop through an array and retrieve JSON data about each item and then populate it.  I know that the below way does not work, because it will cycle through each 'n' before the first response is ever receieved.

What makes sense for me to do is to call the request again in my call back function.  So, after the first response is received it will make a call to get a second response... etc, etc.

Can anyone help me with how I would go about doing something like this?   The end goal is populate each array item with the appropriate response.  I'm new to programming, so this is a little complicated for me.

```
 function getDistance() {

    for (n in addresses()) {
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
          {
              origins: [clientLocation()],
              destinations: [addresses()[n].position()],
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
              avoidHighways: false,
              avoidTolls: false
          }, callbackFunction);
    }



function callbackFunction (response, status) {
    addresses()[n].distanceText(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text)
    addresses()[n].distanceValue(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value)              
    //get the next one??

};
```

}

P.S. I know that I should be sending an array to Distance Matrix Service, and I will, but I want to figure out this problem generally because it presents itself often.

P.P.S.  I'm using knockout.js hence the addresses()[n] call.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arguments.callee` to have a function call itself:

```
function callbackFunction (response, status) {
    addresses()[n].distanceText(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text)
    addresses()[n].distanceValue(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value)              

    //get the next one??
    arguments.callee(response, status);
};
```

I'm unfamiliar with Knockout so you might have to modify that a bit to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but the script will still loop through N before it gets a response..  How do I tell it to loop through each of the array items?

Comment: @RaySülzer you're using a callback function. A callback function says "I don't have data yet, so continue with normal execution and I will execute my logic when I get data." By it's very nature, your code will not execute the response until service.getDistanceMatrix has returned with data.

Comment: But, the issue is that it continues through the loop without applying data to the array...